# Facebooks OAuth dialog doesn't close properly in IE 11

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-oauth

I'm using [FB Client Api for Oauth authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2)

All necessary data after login is recieved while authentication dialog becomes blank and doesn't close after successfull authentication. This behavior is only specific for IE 11. The rest of browsers close Oauth dialog successfully.

Here is init code for FB SDK:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
},
```

This is my init code for FB Login

```
function fbAsyncInit() {
        FB.init({
            appId: options.applicationId, // App ID
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus( callback );
    }

window.fbAsyncInit = window.fbAsyncInit || fbAsyncInit;
```

And the last but not least: authorization function

```
authorize = function() {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    FB.Event.subscribe( "auth.authResponseChange", function( response ) {
        if ( response.status === "connected" ) {
            dfd.resolve();
            return;
        } else {
            FB.login(function() {
                dfd.resolve();
            });
        }
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function( response ) {
        if ( response && response.status === "connected" ) {
            dfd.resolve();
            return;
        }
        FB.login();
    });

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Once again - I recieve all necessary events, problem is that dialog doesn't close after successfull authentication.